# py.test to test flask register, AssertionError: Popped wrong request context

Tags: python, pytest, flask-login

I'm using flask to do register and login:

```
from flask.ext.security.views import register, login

class Register(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return register()

class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return login()

api.add_resource(Login, '/login')
api.add_resource(Register, '/register')
```

then I use py.test to test the class:

```
class TestAPI:
    def test_survey(self, app):
        client = app.test_client()
        data = {'email': 'test@test', 'password': 'password'}
        rv = client.post('/2014-10-17/register',
                          data=json.dumps(data))
        ...
```

when I ran the test, the error occurred as follow:

```
AssertionError: Popped wrong request context.  (<RequestContext 'http://localhost/2014-10-17/register' [POST] of panel.app> instead of <RequestContext 'http://localhost/' [GET] of panel.app>)
```

Do you know why? And when testing login, there was no such error

Answer (score 28):

It's a known flask [problem](https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/21). You receive two exceptions instead one. Simply add `PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False` to your test config.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have to wrap you testing calls with something like this:

```
with self.app.test_client() as client:
    data = {'email': 'test@test', 'password': 'password'}
    rv = client.post('/2014-10-17/register', data=json.dumps(data))
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

When your testA has a syntax error or other exceptions, the `tearDown()` method which does the context pop job will not be reached, so the testA's context wasn't popped correctly. **Then your next test we call it testB will pop the testA's context.** So, that's why you got the error `AssertionError: Popped wrong request context.`.

Check the error in your test code, fix it. Then the `AssertionError` will be gone automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've went to the `flask.ctx.AppContext.__exit__` method and discovered that there was an invisible, unhandled exception in the `exc_value` argument which has  somehow broken the whole thing to pieces.

Comment: I was having the same problem with the exception being thrown on exit from the `with app.app_context():` clause.  I found the problem went away when I set FLASK_DEBUG=0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `rq` and `unittest`.  Solved by checking for `current_app` and `app.testing` and not pushing an `app_context()` if using the single threading `rq` mode.

```
app = current_app or create_app()
if not app.testing:
    app.app_context().push()
```