# Pass WTForms form data to a Celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I want to pass the validated data from a WTForms form to a Celery task. When I try to pass the form, I get `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'MyForm' is not JSON serializable`. How can I pass the data from WTForms to a Celery task? Do I need to write a custom serializer?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/galander/Desktop/Projekty/PDf generator/pdf-generator-master/pdf-generator/main.py", line 64, in submit
generate.delay(form, new_pdf)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 413, in delay
return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 536, in apply_async
**options
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 737, in send_task
amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 554, in send_task_message
**properties
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 169, in publish
compression, headers)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 252, in _prepare
body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
payload = encoder(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 178, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
yield
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 221, in dumps
payload = encoder(data)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 72, in dumps
**dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/home/galander/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 62, in default
return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(o)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
o.__class__.__name__)
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'MyForm' is not JSON serializable
```

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    name_of_the_file = StringField()
    first_name = StringField()
    number = DecimalField()
    date = DateField()

@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    form = MyForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        generate.delay(form)
        return '', 202

    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)

@celery.task()
def generate(form):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what the error is telling you, the celery task is trying to serialize an Object.  That is not possible.

Instead you could serialize the `request.form`.

This is untested, but something like this should work:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
     name_of_the_file = StringField()
     first_name = StringField()
     number = DecimalField()
     date = DateField()

@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.form)

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            generate.delay(request.form)
            return '', 202
    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Comment: That has got me further, thanks ! Atm Celery is showing Runtimeerror: `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.` I need to debug this further.

Comment: Some update - wrapping code inside `@celery.task` with `with app.app_context().push():` causes `AssertionError: Popped wrong app context.`

Comment: [Here is an similar question and answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28139033/5779280).

Comment: I have already found this but thanks ! However, adding `app.config.update(CELERY_BROKER_URL='amqp://localhost//',
 PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION=False)` cuased same error in addition to `AttributeError: __enter__`. Still fighting though