# Flask Pytest throws "Popped wrong request context" error on test_client route get request

Tags: python, flask, pytest

When i'm trying to get "/" route in tests i get an AssertionError:
**AssertionError: Popped wrong request context. (<RequestContext 'http://localhost/' [GET] of project> instead of <RequestContext 'http://localhost/' [GET] of project>)**
My app factory looks like this:

```
def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_map[os.getenv("CONFIG", "dev")])
    initialize_extensions(app)
    return app


def initialize_extensions(app: Flask) -> Flask:
    db.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)
    login.login_view = "login"
    csrf.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes
        from .models import Site, User

    return app
```

and my conftest looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.from_object("project.config.TestingConfig")
    with app.app_context():
        yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def client(app):
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_database(app):
    db.create_all()
    yield db
    db.drop_all()


def test_index(app, client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Also, `assert response.status_code == 200` throws an AssertionError `assert 404 == 200`
What causes the problem?

Comment: You do have `/` route defined in `routes`, right?

Comment: Yeah, i do have it.

Comment: Have you tried configuring the app for testing (`app.config["TESTING"] = True` and also `app.config["PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION"] = False`) as described in the [flask doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#TESTING) and on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28139033/4413446)? My guess is that some exception occurs during the test and it is consumed by Flask instead of being handled by the test.

Comment: @Romain, I have these two settings in a TestingConfig object passed to app config.

Comment: Still happens with Flask 2.2.2, pytest 7.2.0 and Python 10